# Coding style advice/rationale(s) for placing spaces in control statements with C++

Tags: c++, coding-style

Given the following two coding styles, please specify a **rationale** (some pros/cons) for why one would possibly be preferable over the other when writing C++ code.

**(** *Please* do *not* answer with "it is not important"; "just stick to one"; etc. The question is specifically about the possible pro/cons (if any) of the two *spacing* styles below. Thanks. **)**

```
// VARIANT A (NO space after control keyword / space before curly brace)
if(condition) {
  // ...
}
else if(c2) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}

for(int i=0; i<e; ++i) {
  // ...
}

...

// vs. VARIANT B (space after control keyword / NO space before curly brace)

if (condition){
  // ...
}
else if (c2){
  // ...
}
else{
  // ...
}

for (int i=0; i<e; ++i){
  // ...
}

...
```

Note: Apart from taste issues, I am asking this because I see both styles in our code-base and would try to get some arguments for which is to be preferred.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?

Comment: @unwind/maxpm: Why should this be community wiki?

Comment: I like the first style better. This allows me to spot the `{` more easily and faster. Coding style is all about how fast you can read the code, in my opinion.

Comment: What makes you think there's a possible rationale, other than one based on taste or aesthetics?

Comment: I hate both. The curly braces don't align.

Comment: @David: There should be *some* arguments either way that are not purely based on taste. This question is asking for these (plural!). (If there are none, well, bad luck. Then it's all taste. But I'd rather gather some input before concluding this.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I recently fixed some code where a single-line-if was modified and someone forgot to add some braces.

While reading the code, it seemed to me, that the style `...condition){` is harder to read than the style `...condition) {` because the closing `)` and opening `{` are easier to see when separated by a space. (When using Courier New on VS2005 - may be different with different fonts I guess.)

I would also argue that with `if(` the separation is pretty clear without any added whitespace, especially because in a modern editor the `if` will very likely be *colored* differently from the `(`, but `{` will likely have the same color.

Here's a short example:

```
if (pPointer && pPointer->condition(foobar)){
  SendEvent(success_foobar);
  Log(success_foobar);
}
if (pPointer && pPointer->condition(foo))
  SendEvent(success_foo);
  Log(success_foo);
if (pPointer && pPointer->condition(bar)){
  SendEvent(success_bar);
  Log(success_bar);
}
```

vs. this (which I think makes the missing brace a bit clearer):

```
if(pPointer && pPointer->condition(foobar)) {
  SendEvent(success_foobar);
  Log(success_foobar);
}
if(pPointer && pPointer->condition(foo))
  SendEvent(success_foo);
  Log(success_foo);
if(pPointer && pPointer->condition(bar)) {
  SendEvent(success_bar);
  Log(success_bar);
}
```

To sum it up, one may argue that the visual distinction in modern editors is much bigger nowadays, e.g. `if` and `(`, so these do not need spaces, while `(` and `{` are often colored the same and are not as visually distinct and therefore a space may be in order.

Comment: Savvy. Very insightful advice regarding how the editor will likely highlight keywords but not tokens like a parentheses or curly bracket. Curious, which to you prefer: `if(...)` or `if (...)` and which is more widely used in professional industry?

Comment: Hi @Thom - wrt. Space between 'if' and opening paren, I do not have any meaningful preference. Not sure there's *any* industry consensus on these things.

Comment: Always putting the opening curly bracket on the next line, and never using single line 'if' statements also solves this problem

Comment: Why not just do both?

Answer (score 27):

A lot of people get very obsessed about where to place the spaces, braces, parenthesis, brackets, semi-colons and so on whilst at the same time forgetting that the most important thing about source code is that it needs to be understood by another human being.

The compiler couldn't care less about formatting.

After many years in the programming profession, I've come to use this one simple rule:

> Is it easy to read and understand what the code is doing?

It doesn't matter how you format the code, if the above condition isn't met, the code is of poor quality.

I have a personal preference to formatting, and I won't say what it is here as it really doesn't matter what it is.

I find it useful having different programmers code in different styles.

There is of course an exception to this rule: Documentation and tutorial examples should always be consistent - you need to get the reader to follow the important elements being shown and not get sidetracked by the formatting.

Answer (score 25):

Since this is probably much about habit and taste, it might be hard to get any concrete arguments for or against, but here's what I think:

Both works reasonably good, but how would it look to have spaces in function calls? like this:

```
len = strlen (somePtr);
```

That's at least one space too many in my opinion.

Having spaces in that example makes things look more like a control statement than a function call, and I think it is useful to make if/else/while/for stand out a bit.

But I realize this is a pretty subjective view. :)

Comment: +1 - thanks for an argument covering the actual question

Comment: re "spaces in function calls" - I've always avoided this, for the purpose of differentiation from control flow - but, e.g., GNU C encourages `spaces_between_functions_and (their, arguments)`. This starts to make sense when writing code with GLib/GTK+, where things like the `some_method(Instance *instance, other params` make lines quite long, so any visual aids are welcome. With recent snippets of GTK+ I've written (I started on `gtkmm`), I've been trying this, and it seems to help in context.

Comment: I've actually seen your example in the same code as the OP. I've seen codebases where EVERY open paren had a space before it, no exceptions.

Comment: Looks like Haskell with extra parentheses and semicolons. :D

Comment: Space after IF and other keywords, etc. Space before open brace. Space before parenthesis _only_ on function definition/declaration. No Space before parenthesis when _calling_ a function.

Answer (score 7):

I personally prefer this style:

```
if( condition )
    oneLiner();
else if( complicatedCondition(someVar, otherVar) )
{
    more();
    than();
    oneLiner();
}
else if( otherCondition ) // I would prefer to put this in one if with '&&' between conditions...
{
    if( nestedCondition )
        oneLiner();
}
else
{
  // ...
}

for( int i = 0; i<e; ++i )
{
  // ... even for one-liner loops which occasionally might happen
}
```

Why?

1. Braces are aligned
2. No space wasted on oneliner `if`s.
3. Loops are clearly noted with braces (always)
4. Only the outer level has spaces before or after the parentheses. Still a mess if there are more than three levels of function calling involved, like `some( function(calling(another(function())) )`
5. a single space after a semicolon and comma for easy location of these types of delimiters.
6. Nested `if`s need braces around them.

This is of course purely personal, and any comments on my style will be ignored flagrantly ;-)

Comment: That works OK I guess until some programmer updates it along the lines of `oneLiner();` => `if (another_condition) oneLiner ();` and then things go a bit weird.

Comment: Then the nested if needs extra braces of course. Will edit to add that point. Mind you that a single extra condition can be put in the same if with `&&`.

Comment: Well-argued, but I think this wastes vertical space, which makes reading code harder. (Just an subjective opinion of course.)

Comment: ```if( condition )
    oneLiner();```  This "style" has been a contributor to CVEs. Granted the blame CAN be placed on the subsequent contributor who added a line and failed to introduce braces, and granted this got past code review somehow. Style guides exist to minimize mistakes and this is a common example of what not to do.

Answer (score 2):

I typically place spaces between all operators. It's just faster to parse visually. Perhaps if your eyesight is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of modern IDEs and automatic code formatting, this really is neither here nor there. And I wouldn't advice wholesale change of spaces (or any other formatting changes) for existing code in a vcs. Developers will tend to stick to the formatting they are familiar with and as long as the code relays the intention well, where a particular space is inserted is totally redundant IMHO. What you will most likely do is annoy people who are used to doing it one way by enforcing something that is contrived on them...

Focus on the programming problems, not the formatting...